# VBA How to clear favorites folder list in outlook 2010?

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there any way to clear the outlook favorites list in VBA?

Let's say I add a list of folders using the below example:

```
    Sub Technicians()

    Dim strFolders(0 To 2) As String
strFolders(0) = "\\Derp@derp.com\1. Systems and ApplicationsSystem A"
strFolders(1) = "\\Derp@derp.com\1. Systems and Applications\System B"
strFolders(2) = "\\Derp@derp.com\1. Systems and Applications\System C"

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim folder As Outlook.folder
    Dim objNamespace As NameSpace
    Dim objPane As NavigationPane
    Dim objModule As MailModule
    Dim objGroup As NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As NavigationFolder


    Set objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleMail)
        With objModule.NavigationGroups
            Set objGroup = .GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olFavoriteFoldersGroup)
        End With


    index = 0
    For index = 0 To 2
    Set folder = GetFolder(strFolders(index))
        If Not (folder Is Nothing) Then
            Set objNavFolder = objGroup.NavigationFolders.Add(folder)
        End If
    Next index
```

End Sub

```
Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.folder
    Dim TestFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolder_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set TestFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not TestFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = TestFolder.Folders
            Set TestFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If TestFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolder = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the TestFolder
    Set GetFolder = TestFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolder_Error:
    Set GetFolder = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Is there any method or function that I could use that would remove the folders that I added?

I see there is a [remove method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864707(v=office.14).aspx) for folders in msdn, there is no example given and I am not sure how to apply it.

I guess clearing all favorites would be ok too if clearing a specific list is not possible, 
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863914(v=office.15).aspx) method for the Folder class. Here is what MSDN states for the Delete method:

The Delete method deletes a single folder. In general, deleting a folder does not require first deleting the items in the folder. Deleting the folder also deletes all items in the folder. An exception would be if the folder is an Outlook folder that cannot be deleted, such as the Inbox and the Deleted Items folder. In such cases, you can delete only the items of the folder but not the folder itself. To delete all items in the Items collection of the folder, you must delete each item starting with the last item in the folder. For example, in the items collection of a folder, AllItems, if there are n number of items in the folder, start deleting the item at AllItems.Item(n), decrementing the index each time until you delete AllItems.Item(1).